# How to PXE boot a virtual machine from another virtual machine which are in same virtual network?

Tags: boot, kvm-virtualization, maas, pxe

I am doing following tutorial:

- [SecurityTeam/TestingMAAS](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/SecurityTeam/TestingMAAS)

But I cannot get out from 'Commissioning' state of my virtual MaaS nodes to 'Ready' state. Following image shows my current architecture:

[image: private cloud architecture]

Now, I would like to pxe boot MaaS nodes via MaaS Server! I added `<dev root='network' />` to VM's XMLs but when I start them, they just say `not bootable device`. They even do not try to find any DHCP server for pxe boot! I also try to forward UDP packets (tftpd=69, mdnc=68, dhcp=67) from KVM's host to MaaS Server via ip tables but nothing changed!

How I can troubleshoot TFTPD and BOOTP servers at MaaS Server? I could not find any log for them on the system!

Does this architecture allow this booting scenario? If not so, how I should reach the 'Ready' state for my MaaS's nodes!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tons of thanks to [gPXE](http://rom-o-matic.net/gpxe/gpxe-1.0.1/contrib/rom-o-matic), if the node boot up via a gPXE iso as it's cdrom (rather than a network boot), then it can successfully take interaction with MaaS Server and change it's state from `Commissioning` to `Ready`!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're seeing [bug 1051626](http://pad.lv/1051626).

I had to change the next-server in /etc/maas/dhcpd.conf to be the IP of the virbr0 interface.

```
sudo sed -i.dist "s/next-server .*/next-server $MAAS_NEXT_SERVER;/" \
   /etc/maas/dhcpd.conf
sudo service maas-dhcp-server restart
```

Comment: I do NOT have `/etc/maas/dhcpd.conf` on MaaS Server's file system! However, USING SAME CONFIGURATIONS, after some more research I could boot up the node from MaaS Server using gPxe (http://rom-o-matic.net/gpxe/gpxe-1.0.1/contrib/rom-o-matic/). It successfully booted up but always connects to MaaS's apache server to download packages rather than archive.ubuntu.com!!! I'll continue after my new year holidays and let you know ;) thanks

Comment: Hi again; I successfully booted up using `gPxe` (http://rom-o-matic.net/gpxe/gpxe-1.0.1/contrib/rom-o-matic). It started booting from MaaS Server's TFTP, downloaded and installed some staff and finally shutdowned itself. I happily gone to MaaS Server WEB UI but still they're in commissioning state :((

Comment: OK, previuos comment was a temprory unknown problem; I started an amazing new year because finally I bootstrapped `juju` using `gPXE` utility as I described in my answer :) thank you @smoser for developing ubuntu ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you i would consider connecting to your server with virt-manager gui and set it up that way. It gives a better overview - to me it seems you have misconfigured the networking and therefore the nodes can not fetch the IP address...

Comment: but when I boot up another VM in same network via a Live CD (DSL), it can get a new IP from MaaS Server; I verified this by seeing `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Yasser, right.  Its only an issue with the tftp, and my experience was that it was only on the attempt to load the tftp config.  If you're able, just make the tftp server listen on the virbr0 interface address.

Comment: @dhojgaard, the KVM and VMs are on a server machine which cannot have `X Windows` installed; Can `virt-manager` display a remore VM via opening itself via `Xming Server`?

Comment: @YasserZamani
With virt-manager you can connect to the server running the virtual machines. Try to install it on your laptop or a computer running ubuntu desktop and connect to the network with the server and then connect to that server via virt-manager